# How to implement Google Place API in C#.Net

Tags: c#, google-api, google-places-api

I am developing a EPOS System in C#.NET. In My Project, i have to implement a scenario:

1. User will enter Zip Code/ Postal Code in a Text box.
2. Application using google places API will return City, Street and Town separately in 3 Tex box respectively.
   Please any one help me how to implement this scenario in C#.net.

i already created Google Project on https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/key and generate Google Place API Key for my project.

I Have searched a lot on google but all example are implemented in asp.net, but i need in C# Net.
Anyone Help me.
Thanks in Advance.

[image]

> **I have implemented Some how but i don't know how to read it**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
namespace apidemo
{
    class Program
    {
        String response, result;
         const String apiKey= "My APi kEy";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            getdata("B11 4RA");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static async public void getdata(String code)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                   

                    var response = await client.GetStringAsync(String.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key="+ apiKey + "&input=" +code));
               
                    Console.WriteLine(response);
                   



                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.Write(ex.ToString());
            }

          
        }
   

    }
}
```

> **Output is this**
> [image]

Comment: There is not difference between .NET Framework and ASP.NET except UI/Controller related code. Actually, ASP.NET is also a .NET Framework based app.

Comment: @donggas90 i mean c#. net

Comment: Application developing C#.net and asp.net are different, one for Desktop other for We respectively

Comment: Why don't you using Google API libraries for .NET? It should support .NET Standard that is not depend on any runtime platform. .NET Framework, .NET, .NET Core(lagacy of .NET), ASP.NET, ASP.NET Core whatever any of .NET CLR. Therefore, there is no difference.

Comment: Anyway, if you don't using any of library, the HTTP is global standard protocol. Therefore you can call the Google APIs manually by `HttpClient` it is included .NET Standard. It means, all of .NET runtimes support the class.

Comment: Can you share any helpful content that how to use Google API libraries for .NET in my application

Comment: Search the NuGet like this. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis I don't know what packages related with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217192/discussion-between-khuram-shahzad-and-donggas90).

Comment: Plaese edit your question inlcude your code and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.

Comment: @DaImTo OK.....

Comment: @DaImTo i have implement some how but now i am stuck here , How to get desire result from 'responce'

Comment: Have you tried Googleing it? https://stackoverflow.com/q/6620165  Your not going to get the result directly from that response the response is in JSON its going to be up to you to format it.   No one here is going to code your project for you your going to have to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#find-place-responses) for the Google Places API, we can see the format of the JSON that a request to the API returns. You can traverse the json object and get your required values as in below snippet.

```
JObject objectContainer = response.Value<JObject>("candidates");

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> tag in objectContainer)
{
    if(tag.key=="formatted_address")
        var address = tag.value;
    if(tag.key=="name")
        var name = tag.value;
}
```

With a simple HTTP request to the Google Places API, we can then use above code to get required fields.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=YOUR_POSTCODE&inputtype=textquery&&fields=photos,formatted_address,name,opening_hours,rating&key=YOUR_API_KEY");
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlacesApiQueryResponse>(response);
}
```

Comment: use this git project created to help you.its simple https://github.com/Attique033/GoogleAPiC-.git

Comment: That's fine, its return whole string... but i need separately, City, town, Street